A TV movie for kids with some plague in it, 25 years ago
Recently I remembered this movie I watched on TV about 25 years ago, and I would like to see it again. 
Two kids (maybe brother and sister) are travelling the world more or less alone, for some (magical?) reason. The only thing I am sure remember is that they reached a plagued city, where people were covering themselves with black blankets when traveling outside, creating a quite sinister train. It still bothers me to remember. 
I think the world was more or less medieval.
The Plague City was not the only stop in their journey. I think that at some point they were sealed in an tower, but managed to escape with a makeshift glider. I am not 100% confident this was the same show, but I'd love watch it too :)
I think there was something German in the show, but this can be DDR/BRD, Austira or just a memory glitch. 
Which is this movie?

@Richard, Definitely not, but thank you for the link, looks nice :)

Sounds like the Russian fantasy film The Story of Voyages from 1983.

In a medieval fantasy kingdom, two orphans, May and his sister Martha, live in poverty. [...] Martha goes on a quest to find her brother. She is soon joined by a travelling scientist, Orlando. Together, the two wander through various fantastic countries. They visit a city built on the back of a dragon, and see it burnt down when the dragon wakes. In another city, they are sentenced to death for starting a bar brawl. They manage to escape from prison using hang-glider Orlando invented. Finally they land in a country hit by Black Death, which is personified as a witch in black. Orlando sacrifices himself to stop the plague.

The row of people covered in a black blanket is about an hour into it, IIRC. Here's the glider scene:




Great, thank you!
"The row of people covered in a black blanket is about an hour into it" I wonder if I see it again I will be able to unsee it. Finally.
